# Using Rsync and the delta-transfer algorithm in an application

Tags: c++, linux, file, file-transfer

Is it possible to use a server running an Rsync daemon to update program files on the client machine? Is there a library for using as a connector when developing the Rsync client ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not do that if the program files you update on the client machine are often or continuously running -in particular if they are server or daemon programs.

On Linux distributions, the package manager (i.e. `dpkg` on Debian) does a good job for upgrading programs (even for daemons). Can't you use it?

Writing inside a running program binary is error-prone.

There is a [librsync](http://linux.die.net/man/3/librsync) on Linux.

Comment: What I need to update are dll files that are not going to be used at the time of the update (on application startup).And, the application is going to be running on a Windows machine so i can't use dpkg.

Comment: How can I develop the rsync client? Is the a connector/interface library for that ?